# Upload WAMP files to existing Wordpress account?

Tags: wordpress, wamp

I am looking to move my localhost site (WAMP) into my Wordpress account. I have read several articles on how to do it, but with no luck. They all seem to require a web server... Can someone recommend a free one? With instructions on how to upload it online? Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

finally found a method after much googling... 
i ended up choosing x10hosting for web hosting, and i followed this tutorial to install wp plugin and upload files: 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=86y591DokKw

you'll find all your pages, menus, etc missing/incorrect.
so you'll also need to go log onto your localhost wp and export the xml files by:
tools --> export.

then import that file onto x10hosting via wordpress dashboard.
any plugins installed locally will need to be installed again.

hope that helps if anyone else is looking!